# Does anyone have a list of the commands with definitions available for xcode6 in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode6

I learned all of the basic things in Swift like conditional statements, variables, and loops. I went to go make my first app and I noticed that xcode has what appears to be its own set of commands available to program with. An example of this is .textColor . Does anyone have a list of the commands with definitions of what they do. I have looked everywhere and I can't seem to find anything.
Thanks!

Comment: Thank you derdida for you answer. Do you have a link that shows the Class Reference for Swift because the code on the page you shared with me is for Objective-C

Comment: Those aren't commands. They're called properties. Maybe you couldn't find anything because you were searching the wrong term.

Answer (score 1):

Your are looking for the "Class Reference".

Here you find a Reference (for UILabel for Example).

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you have a link that shows the Class Reference for Swift because the code on the page that you shared with me is for Objective-C

Comment: It is still pre release. But you find all the available information here: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/navigation/

Answer (score 0):

Checkout Swifter: http://swifter.natecook.com/v/1.0/ - automatically generated documentation for swift.

Also helpful: use command-click in Xcode on built in methods and classes to see their definitions.